# How do I decrypt a message using openssl's CLI?

Tags: command-line, openssl

I have a message, I know the password and the cipher that was used to encrypt it, but I can't figure out how to ask openssl to decrypt it.

I see the cipher in the output from the `ciphers` command, and the man page lists a `enc` command for `Encoding with Ciphers`, but I can't find how I would do the opposite, decode a message.

Comment: What program is used to encrypt the file? It is very likely that the encryption program adds metadata to the encrypted content, like the initialization vector, salt, version of the program etc. If you treat the whole as encrypted bits, you will get garbage out.

Comment: Late but: `openssl ciphers` lists cipher**suites** for SSL/TLS, which is in practice never password based, and doesn't leave messages anywhere you could later decrypt (i.e. if you have a file, it's not SSL/TLS). `openssl enc` is one commonly used password-based encryption scheme, but there are CMS and (rarely) S/MIME PBEs and a common PGP PBE, and also PBE schemes for _keys_ which are not accurately described as messages, as well as other PBEs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
openssl yourcipher -d < yourfile
```

For example if the file was encrypted using `des3` cipher, and the file is `/path/to/file.des3` then:

```
openssl des3 -d < /path/to/file.des3
```

It will ask you for the passphrase.

If the file is base64 encoded, then you should be able decode and decrypt like this:

```
openssl enc -base64 -d < /path/to/file | openssl yourcipher -d
```

Comment: Trying that, after entering the passphrase, I get "bad magic number". Not sure how to interpret that.

Comment: That error is common when the file is not really an encrypted file... Perhaps you need to unzip it first?

Comment: If I've understood my instructions correctly, my file is base64 encoded (It looks like base64 as well, though that's no guarantee of course). But I've tried passing it through `base64 -d [input] > [output]` and then `openssl [cipher] -d < [output]` as well as deciphering the file as is, and I get the same "bad magic number" in both cases.

Comment: @user50849 I updated my answer thought it looks like you're already doing that... After you decode from base64, what does the `file` command tell you? Is the file binary?

Comment: I tried your added base64 command, and unfortunately I get the same error. file says `data` about the decoded file. I assume that your answer is correct and that something is wrong on my end. Possibly I've corrupted the input or similar. I'll try to work that out and get back.

Comment: Can you ask for a checksum of the file? That way you could confirm if your file is corrupted or not.

Comment: `openssl enc` does base64 itself. If this was in fact the base64 form of `openssl enc`, for which I see no evidence, just `openssl enc -$cipher -d -a` or equivalently `openssl $cipher -d -a`.